# OpenCV - Streaming H264 over RTSP using FFMPEG in version 3.4

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, rtsp

I am trying to capture an `RTSP` stream from a VIRB 360 camera, into `OpenCV`. The video is `H264` and according to one of the comments [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/65932/how-to-stream-h264-video-with-rtsp-in-opencv-partially-answered/), `OpenCV 3.4` should be able to handle it. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720&liveStreamActive=1", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {   
        std::cout << "Input error\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("Video Feed", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cv::Mat frame;
    for(;;)
    {
        //std::cout << "Format: " << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT) << "\n";
        cap >> frame;
        cv::imshow("Video Feed", frame);    
        if (cv::waitKey(10) == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }   
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled `OpenCV` with `ffmpeg` and `gstreamer` capabilities. When I run the following `Gstreamer` command, I am able to stream it, but with a delay of 3 seconds (not acceptable):

```
 gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1
```

On the other hand, I get a 0.5 second delay using `ffplay/ffmpeg` command (acceptable):

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1
```

or

```
ffplay -probesize 32 -sync ext rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720\&liveStreamActive=1
```

In the `OpenCV` code written above, using `cv::CAP_FFMPEG` flag in the line:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720&liveStreamActive=1", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
```

gives the error:

```
[rtsp @ 0x2312040] The profile-level-id field size is invalid (65)
[rtsp @ 0x2312040] method SETUP failed: 461 Unsupported transport
Input error
```

If I use `cv::CAP_GSTREAMER`, it throws no error, but nothing happens. I believe that the problem is that `OpenCV` is not able to handle `UDP` transport layer. What are the possible solutions? Kindly provide suggestions.

**Edit 1:**
I was able to get capture the stream by following [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9292). I made the following changes: instead of `cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720&liveStreamActive=1", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);` the code now has:

```
#if WIN32
    _putenv_s("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "rtsp_transport;udp");
#else
    setenv("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "rtsp_transport;udp", 1);
#endif
auto cap = cv::VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.0.1/livePreviewStream?maxResolutionVertical=720&liveStreamActive=1", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);

#if WIN32
    _putenv_s("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "");
#else
    unsetenv("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS");
#endif
```

However, it throws the following errors:

```
[rtsp @ 0x2090580] The profile-level-id field size is invalid (65)
[rtsp @ 0x2090580] Error parsing AU headers
[h264 @ 0x208d240] error while decoding MB 69 40, bytestream -7
[rtsp @ 0x2090580] Error parsing AU headers
[rtsp @ 0x2090580] Error parsing AU headers
[h264 @ 0x2316700] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 0x2316700] error while decoding MB 0 16, bytestream 112500
[rtsp @ 0x2090580] Error parsing AU headers
```

which means the video is sometimes glitchy and looks like: [image]

I believe it has something to do with:

```
setenv("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "rtsp_transport;udp", 1);
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or improvements. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Set this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 3); /
```

I think this was answered here. [OpenCV VideoCapture lag due to the capture buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032063/opencv-videocapture-lag-due-to-the-capture-buffer)

Comment: The lag is when I am using `gst-launch` command from `gstreamer` in the terminal. In OpenCV, it's not even playing.