# Python Open CV displaying old image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm using Python to try and make a software that just displays a picture of the user, as a test. I do this using Open CV with the following code:

```
import cv2 as cv

cam = cv.VideoCapture(0)
result, image = cam.read()
cv.imshow("USER", image)
cv.waitKey(1000)
cv.destroyWindow("USER")
```

The image displays correctly, but it always uses the image from the previous run. I cannot figure out why this is.

I've browsed the internet and stackoverflow, but no similar issues could be found. Any help would be extraordinary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your camera is buffering more than one frame per shot, according to this [post on the OpenCV forum](https://forum.opencv.org/t/why-does-cv2-videocapture-read-return-the-same-frame-from-a-camera/13339) due to poor lighting conditions some cameras could compensate increasing the exposure to more than one frame, you could try the solution on this post: [OpenCV VideoCapture lag due to the capture buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032063/opencv-videocapture-lag-due-to-the-capture-buffer) and limit the buffer of the camera. Also you should release the camera before the program ends with `cam.release()`.

**A possible solution with this considerations:**

```py
import cv2 as cv

cam = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(cv.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
result, image = cam.read()
if(result):
    cv.imshow("USER", image)
    cv.waitKey(1000)
    cv.destroyWindow("USER")

cam.release()
```

Comment: I tried, and it worked for the first three captures or so. After that, it lost functionality.

Comment: Hi, could you provide more details about your case ? On what OS are you working? Python/OpenCV versions? Are you using a virtualenv? What camera are you using? 
How are you running the code (On the python interpreter o command line)?

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm working with Windows OS, using Python version 3.11.5. I use OpenCV version 4.8.0. I use PyCharm CE, which I believe comes with a venv, but I am not 100% sure. I use a Nexigo webcam, which is my main camera.  I run the code on PowerShell using the `python <filename>` command. Hope that is enough. Thanks for helping me try to fix this!