# Sending and receiving an image, in a Queue, for videostreaming in Flask, high latency. Python

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, queue

I am working on a demonstrator for a Machine Learning based application.

To make things simple, let's assume that :

I am working with two files, run_ml.py and video_stream_flask.py.

The run_ml.py file basically captures an image from the camera, does all the processing, and draws things on the original image.Then, the final image is put in a queue.

This queue is passed among other arguments to a subprocess running the main() of video_stream_flask.py.

The goal here is to get the image from the queue, and display it on a webpage. And in facts, the initial goal is only to be able to display the final image on a webpage.

This is basically the code of the video_stream_flask.py :

```py
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import logging

VERBOSE_DEBUG = 0

if not VERBOSE_DEBUG:
    log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

TARGET = None
queue=multiprocessing.Queue()
global image
image=cv2.imread("output.jpg")

def get_queue(queue):
    try:
        data = queue.get(block=False)
        print("Data retrieved from queue")
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        # print("except : ",e)
        # print("Queue is empty, no data to retrieve.")
        return None

def get_current_ip():
    """
  Get current IP Address by testing IP route
  """
    process_get_ip = subprocess.Popen(["ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}'"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    output = process_get_ip.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
    return output


app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


def gen():
    while True:
        global image
        global queue
        # image = cv2.imread("output.jpg")
        image=get_queue(queue)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            frame = jpeg.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
            print("Frame sent")


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


def main(lan, target,QUEUE):
    global TARGET
    TARGET = target
    global queue
    queue=QUEUE
    
    if bool(lan):
        subprocess.Popen(["ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.20 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
        print("\nCONNECT TO : 10.0.0.20:5000")
        app.run(host="10.0.0.20", port=5000, threaded=True)
    else:
        if TARGET:
            ip_address = get_current_ip()[:-2]
            print("\nCONNECT TO : " + repr(ip_address)[1:-1] + ":5000")
            app.run(host=ip_address, port=5000, threaded=True)
        else:
            print("\nCONNECT TO : localhost:5000")
            app.run(host="localhost", port=5000, threaded=True) #, use_reloader=False
```

The problem I am facing, is the latency. I get instantly almost a ten second latency when viewing the result on my webpage.

I do not understand why.

I have a basic example running, where the image is captured from the camera, directly in the same file and same process, and it works perfectly.

But here, when I try to retrieve the image from the main process, it lags.

I tried other ways of doing so like saving the image in the filesystem and reading it again, with mutexes to make sure there are no conflicts.

When I run my application, I can see on the output that images are yeld as soon as they are ready :

```
Data retrieved from queue
Frame sent

Model Inference time: 926.544ms
Data put into queue successfully.

Data retrieved from queue
Frame sent

Model Inference time: 923.772ms
Data put into queue successfully.

Data retrieved from queue
Frame sent

Model Inference time: 914.210ms
Data put into queue successfully.

Data retrieved from queue
Frame sent
```

Would you have any idea where does the problem comes from ? Or how to do what I want to do, which means, how to stream an image generated in another script, and stream it only once when it is ready ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem was not coming from flask, but from the OpenCV capture.

Explanations about the root cause are available here : [OpenCV VideoCapture lag due to the capture buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032063/opencv-videocapture-lag-due-to-the-capture-buffer)